# Convert an adjacency matrix to From To matrix

Tags: r, graph, transformation, reshape, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to understand graphs and I am using toy dataset as follows

```
df = structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0","1"), class = "factor"), 
                    B= structure(c(1L, 1L,2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0","1"), class = "factor"), 
                    C= structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0","1"), class = "factor"), 
                    D= structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0","1"), class = "factor"), 
                    Weight = c(12, 33, 65, 72, 9, 3, 3, 10, 17, 9, 9, 25, 1, 0, 1, 4)), .Names = c("A","B", "C", "D", "Weight"), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am interested in converting this adjacency matrix above to a From and To matrix something like this.

```
         From     To       Weight
         A        B        72
         A        C        3
         C        D        1
         .        .        .
         .        .        .
         A        D        9
```

So on, any help on how to accomplish this is much appreciated.

-------------user20650  correction-----------

`df = df[-1,]` excluding the first observation

Comment: Im struggling to understand your *adjacency matrix* (i would expect the nrows to equal the ncols) Can you explain what edges and weight of a graph the first row represents please?

Comment: @user20650, good question, you can exclude the first observation from the dataset, `df[-1,]`

Comment: okay, but i just used that as an obvious example. What about the second row? There is a one under node A, to what node does this edge go to / from?

Comment: @user20650, pointing to itself, ?

Comment: How about you edit the data you shared rather than adding code to run to correct it.

Comment: @Gregor, i am not sure what to do, may be I should just delete this question

Comment: When there are more than 2 ones in a row, or no ones in a row, I get confused as to how its an adjacency list. And, this is certainly not an adjacency matrix.

Comment: Typically an [adjacency matrix is square and symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). What you have is neither. If you can edit your question by explaining the meaning of the data frame you do have, perhaps we can still help. I would suggest sharing a short excerpt of your `df` - maybe just the first 3 rows - along with the output you would expect from those three rows, and explain the logic of getting from input to output. Then we can help you code it efficiently.